# How to fix position of TPanel when scrolling on Form

Tags: delphi, tpanel

I'm new to using Delphi so I might need a step-by-step tutorial.

How can I fix the position of a `TPanel` on top of the Form even when scrolling down the Form?

Comment: Could you explain in a bit more detail what exactly the issue is, please? Or maybe even add a code example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: Put a `TScrollBox` on the form with `Align = alClient` and put all of the form's controls inside this, so they have the scroll box as their parent. Then, as a single exception, let the panel be a sibling of the scroll box (that is, the panel's parent is the form, just like the scroll box). Should the panel be aligned to an edge of the form? If so, let it be `Align = alLeft` (`alTop` etc.). Otherwise, make sure it is on the top of the scroll box (but, again, not a child of it).

Comment: thank you for answering, but can you please dumb it down for me. the parent and sibling thing is confusing me. Thank you again

Comment: Andreas is right, but try this explanation.  Put both a `TPanel` and a `TScrollBox` on the form.  Place the `TPanel` at the top (setting `Align` = `alTop` is a good way to do this), and have the `TScrollBox` fill the rest of the space on the form (setting  `Align` = `alClient`).  Then put your other controls (that you want to be able to scroll) on the `TScrollBox`, not directly on the form.